# How to use different user when using github and company's gitlab on the same machine?

Tags: github

When using gitlab built by my company, I have to set the git username as my real name.

Then when I commit to github, it also recognize my real name as username.

How can I change it back to my github account?

Comment: Userinfo for commits has nothing to do with authentication for pushing. Can you specify what exactly you have set up and what isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key for git to recognize user info is user.name and email configs. And these configs can be configed overall or for each project.

So, one way to solve your problem is to add these configs to all your github projects:

```
git config --local user.name "github name"
git config --local user.email "github email"
```